# The top half of larger label sizes get cut off in react-native-simple-radio-button

Tags: css, react-native, radio-button

I am using the [react-native-simple-radio-button](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-radio-button) package. If I specify a fontSize for the label greater than 22, the top half gets cut off. Making the radio buttons even bigger does not seem to make a difference.

Here is my code:

```
let radio_props = [
        {label: 'ABC         ', value: 0},
        {label: 'DEF', value: 1}
]

let menu = <View style={{marginLeft: 40, marginTop: 40}}>
         <RadioForm
             radio_props = {radio_props}
             buttonSize = {40}
             buttonOuterSize={60}
             labelStyle = {{fontSize: 30}}
             initial={this.state.mode}
             formHorizontal={true}
             onPress={(value) => this.onPress(value)}
           />
</View>
```

This code produces the following results:

[image]

Is there something I am doing wrong or is it a bug in the `react-native-simple-radio-button` module?

Comment: Try using `labelWrapStyle` and add certain height into it

Answer (score 0):

Adding padding to the top worked for me

```
labelStyle={{
     fontSize: 30,
     paddingTop: 6                
}}
```